# How to read raw data from disk in mac os

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, macos, filesystems

Question basically as in the title. I could use c/c++/objective-c. I would like to read data from some offset on the disk. Just some basics, I will dig dipper when you show me where :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just open `/dev/rdisk?s?`. They represent the byte sequences on the disk as a device file.